# Does the Diablo 3 public beta share files/resources with the retail download?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm about to uninstall the *D3* public beta and install the pre-release download. Is there any overlap in files (that I'd be deleting and re-downloading)? If so, what do I need to do? I'd prefer to preserve the bandwidth, if possible.

Comment: This is usually always no. But it might be an experiment to copy over the mpqs to the retail directory then do a repair install to validate checksums.

Comment: you still can't get any file from the real game, so it's impossible to say. I took a SS from the error, but not going to create an answer just for this.

Comment: They are different, according to Bashiok (Blizzard Community Manager): https://twitter.com/#!/Bashiok/status/182153526925991937
The beta client will (naturally) have issues that will not be in the retail version.

Comment: VTC as Too localized. This question won't be useful to anyone in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS @Krazer said in the comment of your question.

> They are different, according to Bashiok (Blizzard Community Manager):
>   twitter.com/#!/Bashiok/status/182153526925991937 The beta client will
>   (naturally) have issues that will not be in the retail version. –
>   Krazer

And Bashiok in his Twitter.

> **Aerisot ‏ @Aerisot @Bashiok If we already have the beta client, do we
>   still need to download the retail client?**
>
> ‏ **@Bashiok @Aerisot Yes, they're different.**

And in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/63697/12936) I say all files that are on MAC. And there is a file that saves your preferences called D3Prefs.txt the location is: /Application Support/Blizzard/Diablo III

But as @Bashiok said in his Twitter, the beta is different from the retail version, besides, all your champions and preferences are gonna be reset. So you don't need save any files. And if you did, they are useless to the retail version.

*(You asked the question of the answer that I linked above, so I'm assuming you could use this path better than a windows one. But you can find those files on windows too (some of them at least))*