# How do I fully uninstall the Diablo 3 beta for Mac?

Tags: diablo-iii

The beta doesn't have an uninstaller, [Blizzard's directions](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3595672061) are (by their own admission) not thorough. Where are all of the *D3* directories and preference files, and what is the most effective way to zap them?

Comment: Whenever I have to fully uninstall something, I use [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/). Plus, it's free.

Comment: `Mac apps are notoriously difficult to fully uninstall` -  drag .app file or folder containing it to trash. Empty trash. Exceedingly rare is the program that dumps more than a small plaintext preference file anywhere else on your system.

Comment: "Fully" being the operative word. I've had my fair share of hidden caches.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz apps are always leaving stuff in ~Library and various other places. From memory the StarCraft II demo required cleaning up.

Comment: @row1 Personally, I'm really not going to worry about 10kb of junk .plist files in ~library, which is the majority of what you're talking about. Unless you're troubleshooting, you really shouldn't need to either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Uninstalling applications in Mac OS X is very different than
>   uninstalling in a Microsoft 1Windows environment because Mac OS X has
>   nothing like the Windows Registry.
>
> Most Mac OS X applications (anything that ends in .app), like Safari
>   and iTunes, are bundles. The application icon you see in Finder
>   (typically the Applications Folder) is usually a special folder
>   itself, made to appear as a single double-clickable file. These
>   "folders" contain all, or at least most, of the files needed to run
>   the application, ie they are self-contained. This means that to
>   uninstall these applications, you only have to drag them to the Trash.
>   If you control-click (or right-click) on an Application icon, and you
>   see "Show Package Contents", then it is a bundle.

[Source](http://guides.macrumors.com/Uninstalling_Applications_in_Mac_OS_X)

For Diablo III Beta, you just delete the folder, because it does not create Package Content for you to delete.

But it does create fill .txt files that are not part of the installation.
Here is a screenshot of my Mac with all files with "Diablo" in their name.

[image]

And here's the screenshot with the "Beta" name search:

[image]

Aside from the Diablo III "Beta Setup" that is in my Download folder, there is "[diablo3_beta_enus-driverinfo.txt](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3341768200#7)" that is in **/Users/Shared/Battle.Net/Client/Blizzard Launcher.1454/Support**

The others files are inside the folder in the applications (or in the location you selected).

Also inside **/Users/Shared**, there are 2 folders called: **Battle.net** and **Blizzard**. They are created after you install any Blizzard Game like WoW or SC or Diablo. I don't recommend to your remove those folders, unless you are going to stop playing Blizzard games.

Almost forgot:

There is a file that saves your preferences called D3Prefs.txt the location is: **/Application Support/Blizzard/Diablo III**

Comment: There is a folder in Application Support, too - `~/Library/Application Support/Blizzard/Diablo III`.

Comment: @Adeese you are right. going to fix this.

Comment: If you're going to be thorough enough to look in `~/Library/Application Support`, you should also probably delete the .plist files found in `~/Library/Preferences`. They all share the `com.blizzard.` prefix. You really shouldn't need to delete anything in /Library unless you're troubleshooting a bad install though. 20kb is not going to provide any useful additional storage space on a modern hard drive.

Comment: For me: Just delete the folder will solve the problem. The other files don't mess with nothing and they're not heavy.